# Magento2 OR query on collection

Tags: magento, collections, magento2

We have been trying to make a query when a user apply some filters on front end. We are trying to make OR query in products collection: tried the following but none of them work

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter(['web_mobile_filter','offer_group_name_value'],
            [
                ['in' => '1122'],
                ['in' => '72']
            ]);
```

and

```
  $collection->addAttributeToFilter(
        [
            [
                'attribute' => 'web_mobile_filter',
                'in' => '1122'
            ],
            [
                'attribute' => 'offer_group_name_value',
                'in' => '72,73'
            ],
        ]
    );
```

Can someone help me, find me what i am doing wrong here please?

Comment: you can use like this  
$collection->addAttributeToFilter(array(
              array('attribute' => 'special_price','null' => true),
             array('attribute' => 'product_in_stock','eq' => 1)),
            '',
            'left'
          );

Comment: @faizanbeg thank you. It worked.

Comment: can you plz accept my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can write like this :-

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter( 'web_mobile_filter',
            [         
                'in' => '1122'
            ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
$collection->addAttributeToFilter(array( array('attribute' => 'special_price','null' => true), array('attribute' => 'product_in_stock','eq' => 1)), '', 'left' );
```